# Matching data from two sources and simple calculations in excel

Tags: excel, vba, string-matching, calculated-field

I have some calculations I need to do on a data-set. The calculations are simple (i.e input 1 x input 2 = output), but they take inputs recorded in two different excel workbooks by different people. Due to the different input sources the parameters between the two are sometimes in different orders or with slightly different names - the picture attached should show what I mean.

My plan was to take the relevant sheet of input book 1, and the relevant sheet of input book 2, and copy them into a single workbook where i hope to match the parameters with some sort of lookup/find macro, and perform the calculations automatically using a loop to work across the headers and down the rows

combined worksheet concept
[image]

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are able to **exactly find a common string for the both sheets** in order to use it like a common key, you can do what you need. The string in discussion can be part of the existing columns headers. So, do you? If yes, can you define it and communicate us which is which? Besides that, did you try something on your own? We here help people to correct/improve their  code...

Comment: I do not find any logic in your 'desired output` worksheet. Your first "entry 1/apples "should be 4.31 on my taste. Can you explain what did you try doing when created it?

Comment: Do you have your "some calculations" to be matched in the same workbook, different worksheets and you want to match them on the third worksheet of your workbook in discussion?

Comment: Still alive? Can you answer, at least, to the question able to better clarify your question?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru.. thanks so much for your interest - please don't take my absence as a lack of interest.  It was late, i have worked on this issue for a few weeks and i was at the point ready to give up.

Comment: the logic for the output is just one entry multiplied by the other apples in worksheet 1 - 0.31 * apples worksheet 2 "4", 4x0.31 - 1.24.

Comment: Didn't my code worked as expected? If yes, do you also have other fruit names? Do the string "apple,banana,orange,grape" covers your need in terms of existing in both sheets? Did you try testing of the code? But, 'multiplied'? Not only added? It can be done, but I cannot understand the point...

Comment: The differences in names between sheets are because we are given specimens to work on - they may be "apples", "oranges" etc.. but they always come one specimen of each type only, along with some extra record keeping identifiers.  Everyone else i work with keeps to a strict naming scheme with the specimen types and identifiers, however one person responsible for one of these inputs makes up their own naming at whim and refuses to understand the benefits of consistency.  I have tried a bunch of stuff i will post now - but it is all terrible, im only a beginner VBA user!

Comment: im just about to implement it.  GIve me 2 minutes!  thought i would thank you first for your efforts

Comment: If one of the fruit name does not match its corespondent in the reference string ("apple,banana,orange,grape"), you can change something able to cover both situations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you look less interested than me to solve this problem,  I prepared the next code with the assumption that the array obtained from the the string "apple,banana,orange,grape" covers both sheets strange style head of columns naming.

I used "X1" for your first sheet name, "X2" for the second one and "Result" for the one matching values of the first two:

```
Sub MatchingLike_bis()
  Dim arrNames As Variant, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sRez As Worksheet
  Dim lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long, arrRez As Variant, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
  Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, El As Variant, k As Long, col1 As Long, col2 As Long
  Dim strProbl1 As String, strProbl2 As String, colTot As Long, boolF As Boolean, i As Long

  arrNames = Split("apple,banana,orange,grape,lemon", ",")
  colTot = UBound(arrNames) + 2 'The array is zero based and A is excepted

  Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X1")
  Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X2")
  Set sRez = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
   lastR1 = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

   arr1 = sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(1, 1), sh1.Cells(lastR1, colTot)).Value
   arr2 = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, 1), sh2.Cells(lastR1, colTot)).Value

   'preliminary check if all fruits name has a corespondent in both necessary sheets:__________
   strProbl1 = "": strProbl2 = ""
   For Each El In arrNames
        For i1 = 2 To colTot 'make checking in first sheet
            If InStr(UCase(arr1(1, i1)), UCase(El)) > 0 Then
                boolF = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next i1
        If Not boolF Then strProbl1 = strProbl1 & El & vbCrLf
        boolF = False
        For i2 = 2 To colTot 'make checking in the second sheet
            If InStr(UCase(arr2(1, i2)), UCase(El)) > 0 Then
                boolF = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next i2
        If Not boolF Then strProbl2 = strProbl2 & El & vbCrLf
        boolF = False
   Next
   If strProbl1 <> "" Then MsgBox "In " & sh1.Name & " sheet, the next fruit names are" & _
                " incorrect, or missing:" & vbCrLf & _
                vbCrLf & strProbl1 & vbCrLf & "Please correct the spelling and run the application again!", _
                vbInformation, "Wrong spelling in " & sh1.Name & " worksheet": sh1.Activate: Exit Sub
   If strProbl2 <> "" Then MsgBox "In " & sh2.Name & " sheet, the next fruit names are" & _
                " incorrect, or missing:" & vbCrLf & _
                vbCrLf & strProbl2 & vbCrLf & "Please correct the spelling and run the application again!", _
                vbInformation, "Wrong spelling in " & sh2.Name & " worksheet": sh2.Activate: Exit Sub
   '_________________________________________________________________________________________________

   ReDim arrRez(1 To UBound(arr1, 1), 1 To colTot) 'result array will have exactly the
                                                   'number of rows and columns as arr1
   For i1 = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
     If i1 = 1 Then
        arrRez(i1, 1) = Empty
        For i = 2 To colTot
           arrRez(i1, i) = arr1(i1, i)
        Next i
     Else
        For i2 = 1 To UBound(arr2, 1)
            If arr1(i1, 1) = arr2(i2, 1) Then
                arrRez(i1, 1) = arr1(i1, 1)
                'find the right reference in the accepted keys array:
                For Each El In arrNames
                    For k = 2 To colTot
                        If InStr(UCase(arr1(1, k)), UCase(El)) > 0 Then col1 = k
                        If InStr(UCase(arr2(1, k)), UCase(El)) > 0 Then col2 = k
                    Next k
                    If col1 > 0 And col2 > 0 Then
                        arrRez(i1, col1) = arr1(i1, col1) + arr2(i2, col2)
                        col1 = 0: col2 = 0
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next i2
     End If
   Next i1
   With sRez.Range(sRez.Range("A1"), sRez.Cells(lastR1, colTot))
    .Value = arrRez
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With
End Sub
```

This version allows adding of a new fruit name in the string "apple,banana,orange,grape,lemon" (I already added lemon) and the code adapts itself to return as many columns as necessary. It makes a preliminary check and sends relevant messages for fruit names wrongly spelled in both input sheets. The code will completely run only if all the fruit names are matched in both input sheets...

Comment: Thank you!  this worked fore everything except the bananas for some reason!

Comment: this was my 1st attempt at just matching the two things (without the fruit examples)... i didnt even get to the calculation stage     Sub dividing_mass_by_volume()

    Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As String
    ValueToFind = Sheets("compound flow rates").Range("C1:BF1") ''setting comparison
    For i = 3 To 58   'trying to search one row (100) from C to BF
        If Sheets("data_inputs").Cells(i, 100).Value = StringValueToFind Then
        Cells("i, -1").Formula = "found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Comment: Please, post here how 'banana' is spelled in both your sheets and I am sure, we will find a solution...

Comment: yeah, you got me - it was a typo!

Comment: I really do appreciate the help, but i cant get it to work for my specific application.  Am i right in thinking that to increase the fruit numbers  i would need to write the following expressions for each one, so to go beyond column E i would need to write the for arrREZ(i1, 6,7,8, etc...For i1 = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
     If i1 = 1 Then
        arrRez(i1, 1) = Empty
        arrRez(i1, 2) = arr1(i1, 2): arrRez(i1, 3) = arr1(i1, 3)
        arrRez(i1, 4) = arr1(i1, 4): arrRez(i1, 5) = arr1(i1, 5) for

Comment: OK. But I didn't meant to get you... Even if it was a typo, it  may happen in the future again. So, which was the difference, in order to choose another string able to cover both situations? In fact, I am thinking to preliminary  check if the string can be found in both sheets and rise a message warning for the fruit name in discussion...

Comment: @plorpoise: It is good/recommended to tell us in your question everything about your real situation. I can adapt the code in order to need only inputting of a new fruit name  in the string. And the application will count how many fruits must be checked. You can use any number you want, in principle, but not with the existing code... I did not know anything about your VBA skills. I thought if I will provide you a solution, maybe, after understanding its logic you will adapt it to serve to your purpose... When I will find some time, I will adapt it as I said.

Comment: the typo - i typed out the sheets again and wrote "banans" in one worksheet - obvious error..  but the absence of data was a clear indicator.. i think the bigger problem might be scaling it up for what i need (90 plus fruit and counting).. thanks again! i am out for the night, but you've given me an awesome starting point

Comment: like i said i appreciate it.. i can get VBA to copy paste and a few other things.. the babiest of baby steps.. i dont expect you to put more work into it.. i will keep looking at it and eventually something will start to click!  (i thought i would be able to adapt it too! - and i will hopefully). thanks!

Comment: @plorpoise: I will adapt the code, in order to only need introducing of the new fruit name in the (existing) string `"apple,banana,orange,grape". Only to be separate by a comma... Keep the existing version and compare it with the new one, only for a didactic reason. To learn something... :). Now, the columns number is a fix one. It must be calculated starting to the string number of elements.

Comment: @plorpoise: I adapted to code to work for as many fruit names you need. It is enough to ad a fruit name in the string "apple,banana,orange,grape". Like you can see, I already added 'lemon'. The code makes a preliminary check for involved fruit names in both input files and completely runs only after the check passed. It returns as many columns (fruit names) exists. Please check it and let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: it seems to work! beautiful effort.. i really need to sit and go through it step by step to figure it out. The lemons example works beautifully - when i apply to my data it points out some name mismatch errors that don't appear to be errors - but i really want to try and work out why that is myself.

Comment: looks like it is spaces in one entry and not the other.  Really appreciate all the hard work @FaneDuru... i think what i should have done is worked on something simpler just to get the names lined up properly, which would have probably made all this easier. i will do that now.  thanks again :) !!!

Comment: My code helps you now to identify the misspelled fruits names and it shouldn't be so difficult, I think...